# Round to specific number

Tags: javascript, rounding

I am looking for a standard JS method which basically does that:

```
iRoundTo1 = Math.abs(1000000 - myValue);
iRoundTo2 = Math.abs(2000000 - myValue);
iRoundTo5 = Math.abs(5000000 - myValue);

myValue = Math.min(iRoundTo1, iRoundTo2,
        iRoundTo5);

if (myValue === iRoundTo1) {
    myValue = 1000000;
} else if (myValue === iRoundTo2) {
    myValue = 2000000;
} else if (myValue === iRoundTo5) {
    myValue = 5000000;
}
```

As described in the title I want my value to be rounded to specific numbers i.e. 1M, 2M and 5 M.

Comment: There is no standard way to do this. You either write this yourself or use a library.

Comment: You can easily round it to millions, but you can't skip the other values, like 0, 3, 4, 6 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you have to implement such special thing yourself.
If you just want some fancy one line solution to make your code cleaner:

```js
var myValue = 1234567;
var rounded = [1000000,2000000,5000000].reduce((y,x)=>{return y.diff == undefined || Math.abs(x-myValue) < y.diff ? {val:x,diff:Math.abs(x-myValue)} : y},{}).val;
console.log(rounded);
```

Or you can just declare a function to make it even more cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, i kinda hoped there already was a solution for it... but i think i am gonna pass on the one liner, i think the multiple line solution is easier to read and i dont really need to worry about performance

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if that's what you want, but here is my suggestion:

```
const temp = Math.abs(myValue / 1000000) * 1000000;
```

If will basically round down the absolute value to the closest "million".

You can add `if` or `switch` statement to convert it to predefined values depending on the case. This will already reduce the boilerplate needed in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code you want.

```js
function formatMoney(n, c, d, t) {
  var c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
    i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;

  return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
}

function numShort(value){
    if(value < 1000000){
      return formatMoney(value, 2, ".", ",");
    }else if(value < 1000000000){
      return formatMoney((value/1000000), 2, ".", ",")+'m';
    }else{
      return formatMoney((value/1000000000), 2, ".", ",")+'b';
    }
}

console.log(numShort(100));
console.log(numShort(1000));
console.log(numShort(10000));
console.log(numShort(100000));
console.log(numShort(1000000));
console.log(numShort(10000000));
console.log(numShort(100000000));
console.log(numShort(1000000000));
console.log(numShort(10000000000));
console.log(numShort(100000000000));
```